# Thingsboard installation using docker on Ubuntu

Tags: thingsboard

I'm facing issues when installing thingsboard using docker-compose on ubuntu

images are correctly pulled , container seems to be up but logs shows :

logs for thingsboard/application:1.2.2 :

> thingsboard-db-schema container is still in progress. waiting until it
>   completed...
>
> thingsboard-db-schema container is still in progress. waiting until it
>   completed...
>
> thingsboard-db-schema container is still in progress. waiting until it
>   completed...
>
> thingsboard-db-schema container is still in progress. waiting until it
>   completed...
>
> thingsboard-db-schema container is still in progress. waiting until it
>   completed...
>
> thingsboard-db-schema container is still in progress. waiting until it
>   completed...
>
> logs for thingsboard/thingsboard-db-schema:1.2.2
>
> Wait for Cassandra...
>
> Failed to resolve "db".
>
> WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
>
> Wait for Cassandra...
>
> Failed to resolve "db".
>
> WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
>
> Wait for Cassandra...

seems that the first container waiting cassandra to be up which is not the case

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check output of the DB container using command **'docker-compose logs -f db'** and verify that *cassandra* is ready to accept client on **9042** port:

```
db_1 | INFO  11:02:07 Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
db_1 | INFO  11:02:15 No gossip backlog; proceeding
db_1 | INFO  11:02:15 Netty using native Epoll event loop
db_1 | INFO  11:02:15 Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork19.fe4816e, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86]
db_1 | INFO  11:02:15 Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...
```

Output should be like logs above.

Plus **additionally** verify that no errors happened during the **cassandra** start up.